# Can i post message via incoming webhook connector in teams, but not as Card, just plain text?

Tags: webhooks, microsoft-teams, connector

I can't find microsoft documents how to change the sample command:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"text\": \"Hello World\"}" <YOUR WEBHOOK URL>
```

to send the message as plain text instead of Card.

I do not want to send messages as a Card, because in notifications on the computer and on mobile devices, only "card" is displayed instead of the message content.

Comment: to avoid "Card" in the notification, you can add "summary" in your POST request and it (or part of it) will be displayed instead

Answer (score 0):

@kacper Pazur, You can not send message as text using incoming webhook. Even if you remove the content-type - it will still go in card format. for more details please check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using).

Comment: At the beginning of this documentation we can read:
"Typically this payload will be in the form of an Office 365 Connector Card."
I understand this by saying that Card is the most common or default way to display a message.
Do you suggest another solution to publish on the channel teams "simple message" in an automated way?

Comment: Any update on this?